# C# Time Zone Logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

We currently self-host an application in MST but users in all timezones access this application. The bad part is that it always points to the Server in MST and subsequently appointments made are showing up as times in MST instead of EST, CST, etc.

I was able to go into IIS and find a .cs file that contains the following code. I am not sure if this definitively is the DateTime object it is pointing to, but any assistance is greatly appreciated.

I'm rusty on my C# logic but what I can remember is that DateTime.Now points back to the time zone of the server but can a DateTime.Offset use the timezone of the end user computer?

```
public DataTable dtEvents = new DataTable();
    public DataRow dtRow;
    public string sST = "12:00 AM";
    public string sET = "11:59 PM";
    public string sSD = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    public string sED = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    public string todayDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    public string startDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    DateTime dtST = DateTime.Now; //row.StartTime;
    DateTime dtET = DateTime.Now; //row.EndTime;
    //object[] AppointmentData = new object[15]; 
 DateTime dtToday = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 7, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Clearly the person who write your DB/app didn't see the sense in converting all times to UTC for storage, and storing the timezone they need to be expanded back to to make sense to the user. Life gets a boatload easier when you use `UtcNow` all through your code except right at the last second when you convert that time to local for whatever user is looking at the appointment `<div` in the webpage.. Does any of the time data in the DB contain the zone ? Is the date+zone stored directly? Looks like theyve gone to some effort to format stuff as strings; there might be something useful in there

Comment: DateTime dtToday = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 7, 0, 0);

Comment: Yep, it's getting worse! Rip it all out, starting with a Ctrl-F on `DateTime.Now`

Comment: I recommend you read this blog before you do any refactoring - [Storing UTC Is Not a Silver Bullet - Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/). It should help you make sense of what you *should* be storing and knowing that will help you figure out what changes you have to make to your app.

Comment: **Offset != Time Zone**. Be careful not to conflate the two. A time zone has the rules for when to change the offset forward or back. For example, New York and Chile are standard at `-05:00` but when they change to `-04:00` and back is different. With just an offset, you can't know. After you read that blog, I suggest you do some in-depth testing of your logic using *only* [NodaTime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NodaTime) types. It may be difficult at first, but it will force you to think about the problem correctly and then you can refactor with greater confidence.

Comment: @CaiusJard the OP mentioned "appointments"... Storing UTC for those is not necessary the right thing - "wake me up 9am" does not really mean any UTC time at all for all *normal* people. We as developers understand those people are totally wrong and everyone must wake up 00:09UTC and it user's fault to wish to sleep at night :)

Comment: Plot twist, that this is a EHR program. The clinicians access it through a VPN via AD authentication. would those two entities revert the time back to MST? Sorry, i should have stated that at the beginning.